# Several domains and only one redirection needed on htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-6

I have several domains, but i will take the case of only two different domains domain1.com and domain2.com. Only the first one has a mobile version whose URL os m.domain1.com, I don't have a mobile version for the second one.

Both domains are in the same filepath (on drupal), so when a user tries to go any of those domains (domain1.com and domain2.com) from a mobile device, the user is redirected to m.domain1.com

So, what I want is that when a mobile device connects to domain2.com it serves domain2.com (no redirection needed), and only when it connects to domain1.com, the redirection to m.domain1.com should happen

This is what I got in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.domain1.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Drop the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$` line, change the rule to `RewriteRule ^$ http://m.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=302]`. Although you may want to lob off a possible `www.` prefix there.

Comment: Thanks! But only domain1.com has a mobile version. What this did was redirect all domains to m.(any_domain_here).

Comment: Hm, then your original code should work.... But you could omit the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.` then.... Or are we running into the problem you go there by www.domain1.com rather then domain1.com? 'cause then I'd use `^(www\.)?domain1.com$` instead.

Comment: Well, not really. What's happening is, if I go to domain2.com (hosted on the same server), it'll redirect. That shouldn't be.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$` should be false then, unless that domain2.com is proxied in a very weird way instead of arriving directly... If you're working in Drupal, could you share what `$_SERVER` holds if you're going to domain2.com? `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` _should_ be `domain2.com` at that point, but if it isn't... there's something else going on.

Comment: Solved it! here it goes:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ara\.com\.mx [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ http://m.ara.com.mx/ [L,R=302]

That does it!

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes! Thanks for your help!!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.domain1.com [L,R=302]
```

Hope someone can use this!